# Are all page changes in Facebook Canvas App supposes to first redirect to FacebookRedirect.axd

Tags: c#, facebook, canvas, sdk

I have a Facebook Canvas app that works. It is a vb.net website using Facebook C# SDK. I noticed that when clicking a link to change from one .aspx page to the next it always redirects to FacebookRedirect.axd and then to the page. Is this normal and expected with all facebook canvas apps?